# Como reiniciar un setInterval en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo un temporizador que inicia en 90 segundos que es el tiempo que tiene la persona para responder una pregunta si el temporizador llega 0 la persona no puede seguir respondiendo las preguntas, el problema que tengo es cuando la persona responden la pregunta antes de que el temporizador llegue a 0 ya que al cargar la nueva pregunta y hacer el llamado a la funcion la secuencia no se reinicia si no que el reloj nuestra el tiempo restante de la pregunta anterior y de la pregunta nueva. la ayuda que necesito es poder reiniciar el contador y que solo se vea el conteo nuevo.

```html
<div id="timer_container" class="col-md-3">
  <p id="timeClock" style="color: #FFF;"></p>
</div>
```

```
function timerClock(timeFull){

  var timeleft, time;
  timeleft = time = timeFull;
  $("#timeClock").html(timeleft);
  $("#timer_container").fadeTo("slow",1);
  $("#timeClock").fadeTo("slow",1);
  var i, j, rotation, width;  

  for(i=0; i<timeleft;i++){
    document.getElementById("timer_container").innerHTML += "<div class='tictic'></div>";
  } 
  var x = document.getElementById("timer_container");
  var y = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
  width = document.getElementById("timer_container").offsetWidth;
  for(i=0; i<timeleft;i++){
    rotation=(360/timeleft)*(i);
    y[i].style.cssText = "transform:rotate("+ rotation +"deg) translate(0px, -"+width/2+"px)";
  }
  var i = 0;
  remainingtime = setInterval(function(){
    $("#timeClock").html(timeleft);
    y[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    timeleft -= 1;
    i+=1;
    if(timeleft <= 0 && i>=time){
      clearInterval(remainingtime);
      //$("div").remove(".tictic");
      //PlaySong("fin_play");
      $("#timeClock").html(0);
    }
  }, 1000);

}
```

Comment: Lo que buscas es: [`clearInterval(remainingtime)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval). Saludos

Comment: Intente con esa opción al inicio de la función pero no funciono aunque no se como recomiendas que se use

Comment: Amigo, no lo digo en mala onda, pero hay varias cosas que están mal en el código, por ejemplo veo que redeclaras la variable global i en la misma parte del código, eso no es conveniente si la variable ya fue declarada, lo otro es que no necesitas 2 ciclos for e iterar tantas vecez sobre ellos para esas transformaciones, estas consumiendo CPU innecesario, porfavor trata de editar tu código y hacerlo un poco mas legible para nosotros, te dare una pista, con ese setInterval que tienes puedes hacer las vecez de esos dos ciclos for que tienes, solo debes gestionar el cómo.

Comment: Gracias por tus recomendaciones, pero no me queda claro lo que hablas respecto  de reemplazar los dos ciclos for por el setInterval agradecería un poco mas de claridad

Answer (score 2):

No dejas clara la estructura de tu página, y pues veo mucho enredo en tu JS, es decir mezclas presentación con lógica. Eso no lo tomes a mal, al contrario es una recomendación que te puedo dar por el poco código visto. Intenta mejorar un poco tu código para que se vea más limpio, separando la lógica de la presentación. Me refiero a la cantidad de estilos en linea que metes para animaciones y demás.

**PROBLEMA**

Necesitas reiniciar el temporizador cada vez que se realiza una acción. En tu caso la acción es responder una pregunta.

Cada pregunta tiene un tiempo máximo de respuesta de 90 segundos. Si el usuario no responde una pregunta en ese tiempo, no puede seguir respondiendo, es decir pierde la oportunidad de seguir respondiendo.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero, **no uses** [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) para controlar el tiempo que tiene para responder la pregunta, **debes usar** [`setTimeOut()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). La función `setInterval()` la usarás simplemente para mostrar el tiempo restante de cada pregunta.

¿Porqué?

La traducción de *timeout* te lo dice: "tiempo agotado". Y es que cada pregunta tiene un tiempo para ser respondida, si se agota dicho tiempo, se acaba todo, incluida la posibilidad de seguir respondiendo.

Usamos `setInterval()` cuando necesitamos que una acción se repita indefinidamente en el tiempo, cada *x* cantidad de tiempo, desde el momento en que se llama a su ejecución. Por ejemplo:

- Mostrar los segundos transcurridos en un reloj.
- Realizar una solicitud AJAX para actualizar un dato.
- Cambiar la vista, para sacar de sus casillas al usuario (muy mala cosa, no lo hagan).

¿Cómo lo implemento?

Vamos a hacer un seudoprograma para ver la lógica de cómo podríamos implementar esto usando `setTimeout()` y `setInterval` de una forma un poco más lógica.

1. Inicia la tanda de *n* preguntas.
2. Se presenta una pregunta y se inicia el *temporizador* de 90 segundos.

   2.1. Si el usuario responde la pregunta, se cancela el *temporizador* y se repite el paso 2.

   2.2 Si el usuario no responde la pregunta, se termina el ciclo de preguntas.
3. Se presenta el resultado del programa.

Sencillo, ¿cierto?

Vamos ahora a recrearlo con código. Primero vamos a elegir 5 preguntas cerradas (cuyas respuestas sean si o no). Luego crearemos una plantilla para presentar las preguntas, en dicha plantilla habrá 2 botones (puedes poner 2 elementos `input` tipo `radio` y un botón, pero eso implica 2 clic por parte del usuario). Al final, si el usuario responde todas las preguntas o se le acaba el tiempo en alguna de ellas, se muestra el resultado de sus respuestas. La lógica de saber si sus respuestas son válidas no entra en este ejemplo.

La plantilla HTML:

```html
<div id="contenedor">
    <div id="pregunta"></div>
    <div id="timer"></div>
    <div id="botones">
      <button class="button" id="iniciar" type="button">Iniciar</button>
      <button class="button" id="si" type="button" disabled>Si</button>
      <button class="button" id="no" type="button" disabled>No</button>
      <button class="button" id="ver" type="button" disabled>Ver Resultado</button>
    </div>
    <div id="resultado">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ahora la lógica: (Usaremos JQuery ya que es lo que se aprecia en tu código)

```js
// Variable global para setInterval
let interval;

// Variable global para setTimeOut
let timeout;

// Variable global para pregunta
let pregunta;

// Variable global para el tiempo de respuesta
const time = 10000; // <- aquí puedes variar según necesites, puse 10 segundos

// Variable global para mostrar el cronómetro
let refreshTime;

// Lista global de preguntas
const preguntas = [
  '¿Javascript es un lenguaje tipado?',
  '¿Es válida la siguiente expresión: <code>const var = "my var";</code>?',
  '¿La empresa detrás de la creación de Javascript es Oracle?',
  '¿El resultado del siguiente código es "false"? <code>let result = (3 + 5) === 7 || 6;</code>',
  '¿El siguiente es un tipo de dato en Javascript: <code>undefined</code>'
]

// Variable global para almacenar las respuestas
const respuestas = [];

// Función que se ejecutará al terminar el tiempo para responder.
const onTimeOut = function() {
  window.clearInterval(interval); // <- aquí borramos el intervalo
  $('#timer').html(`Tiempo restante: 0 segundos`); // <- mostramos el tiempo en 0
  $('#si').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#no').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#ver').removeAttr('disabled');
  alert('Tiempo excedido');
}

// función que maneja el evento `click` del botón iniciar.
const onIniciar = function(event) {
  $('#iniciar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#si').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#no').removeAttr('disabled');
  mostrarPregunta();
}

// Función que manejará el evento click sobre los botones `si` y `no`
const onResponse = function(event) {
  if(timeout) window.clearTimeout(timeout); // <- Si ya hay un timeout lo limpiamos
  if(interval) window.clearInterval(interval); // <- Si ya hay un interval lo limpiamos
  const respuesta = event.target.id; // <- obtenemos la respuesta
  respuestas.push({pregunta: pregunta, respuesta: respuesta}); // <- guardamos el resultado
  if(preguntas.length) { // si todavía hay preguntas mostramos la siguiente
    mostrarPregunta();
  } else { // si no hay más preguntas hemos terminado
    $('#si').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#no').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#ver').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}

// Función para manejar el evento click del botón resultado
const onResultado = function() {
  $('#resultado').append('<H5>Resultado</H5>');
  if(respuestas.length) {
    $('#resultado').append('<ul>');
    respuestas.forEach(respuesta => {
      $('#resultado').append(`<li>${respuesta.pregunta}: Usted respondió: ${respuesta.respuesta}</li>`);
    });
    $('#resultado').append('</ul>');
  } else {
    $('#resultado').append('Vuelve a intentarlo');
  }
}

// Función para mostrar una pregunta
const mostrarPregunta = function() {
  // sacamos la pregunta de la lista
  pregunta = preguntas.shift();
  $('#pregunta').html(pregunta);
  // actualizamos el timer con el tiempo restante en segundos
  $('#timer').html(`Tiempo restante: ${time / 1000} segundos`);
  // establecemos el valor para mostrar en el timer
  refreshTime = time - 1000;
  // iniciamos interval y timeout
  interval = window.setInterval(actualizarTimer, 1000);
  timeout = window.setTimeout(onTimeOut, time);
}

// Función para actualizar el timer
const actualizarTimer = function() {
  $('#timer').html(`Tiempo restante: ${refreshTime / 1000} segundos`);
  refreshTime -= 1000;
}

// manejadores de evento click
$('#iniciar').click(onIniciar);
$('#si').click(onResponse);
$('#no').click(onResponse);
$('#ver').click(onResultado);
```

La aplicación inicia al momento que se hace clic en el botón `Iniciar`, en dicho momento se cambian las propiedades de los botones de respuesta y se llama a la función `mostrarPregunta()`, la cual se encarga de establecer `interval` y `timeout`.

Cada vez que el usuario responde a la pregunta, usando alguno de los botones de respuesta, se vuelven a reestablecer `interval` y `timeout` y se llama nuevamente a la función `mostrarPregunta().`

Cuando ya no hay más preguntas por mostrar (o cuando se agota el `timeout`), se habilita el botón de mostrar resultado.

Cuando se llama a la función `setInterval()`, la misma ejecutará por primera vez el código cuando pase el tiempo que le hemos pasado como segundo argumento. Es por ello que antes de hacer el llamado a `setInterval()`, mostramos el tiempo completo en el elemento `timer` y establecemos el valor inicial (`refreshTime`) un segundo menos del valor inicial, para que al momento de ejecutarse la función, muestre correctamente el valor restante.

Ahora le damos un poco de visibilidad con estilos básicos:

```css
/* Contenedor principal */
#contenedor {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Contenedor para las preguntas */
#pregunta {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Contenedor para el timer */
#timer {
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

/* Contenedor para los botones */
#botones {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Elemento botón */
.button {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
```

El código en conjunto puede verse así:

```js
// variable global para setInterval
let interval;

// variable global para setTimeOut
let timeout;

// variable global para pregunta
let pregunta;

// variable global para el tiempo de respuesta
const time = 10000; // <- aquí puedes variar según necesites, puse 10 segundos

// variable global para mostrar el cronómetro
let refreshTime;

// lista de preguntas
const preguntas = [
  '¿Javascript es un lenguaje tipado?',
  '¿Es válida la siguiente expresión: <code>const var = "my var";</code>?',
  '¿La empresa detrás de la creación de Javascript es Oracle?',
  '¿El resultado del siguiente código es "false"? <code>let result = (3 + 5) === 7 || 6;</code>',
  '¿El siguiente es un tipo de dato en Javascript: <code>undefined</code>'
]

//variable para almacenar las respuestas
const respuestas = [];

//función que se ejecutará al terminar el tiempo para responder.

const onTimeOut = function() {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
  // ocultarPregunta();
  $('#timer').html(`Tiempo restante: 0 segundos`);
  $('#si').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#no').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#ver').removeAttr('disabled');
  alert('Tiempo excedido');
}

// función que maneja el evento `click` del botón iniciar.
const onIniciar = function(event) {
  $('#iniciar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#si').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#no').removeAttr('disabled');
  mostrarPregunta();
}

const onResponse = function(event) {
  if(timeout) window.clearTimeout(timeout);
  if(interval) window.clearInterval(interval);
  const respuesta = event.target.id;
  respuestas.push({pregunta: pregunta, respuesta: respuesta});
  if(preguntas.length) {
    mostrarPregunta();
  } else {
    $('#si').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#no').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#ver').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}

// Función para manejar el evento click del botón resultado
const onResultado = function() {
  $('#resultado').append('<H5>Resultado</H5>');
  if(respuestas.length) {
    $('#resultado').append('<ul>');
    respuestas.forEach(respuesta => {
      $('#resultado').append(`<li>${respuesta.pregunta}: Usted respondió: ${respuesta.respuesta}</li>`);
    });
    $('#resultado').append('</ul>');
  } else {
    $('#resultado').append('Vuelve a intentarlo');
  }
}

// Función para mostrar una pregunta
const mostrarPregunta = function() {
  pregunta = preguntas.shift();
  $('#pregunta').html(pregunta);
  $('#timer').html(`Tiempo restante: ${time / 1000} segundos`);
  refreshTime = time - 1000;
  interval = window.setInterval(actualizarTimer, 1000);
  timeout = window.setTimeout(onTimeOut, time);
}

// Función para actualizar el timer
const actualizarTimer = function() {
  $('#timer').html(`Tiempo restante: ${refreshTime / 1000} segundos`);
  refreshTime -= 1000;
}

$('#iniciar').click(onIniciar);
$('#si').click(onResponse);
$('#no').click(onResponse);
$('#ver').click(onResultado);
```

```css
/* Contenedor principal */
#contenedor {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Contenedor para las preguntas */
#pregunta {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Contenedor para el timer */
#timer {
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

/* Contenedor para los botones */
#botones {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Elemento botón */
.button {
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="pregunta"></div>
  <div id="timer"></div>
  <div id="botones">
    <button class="button" id="iniciar" type="button">Iniciar</button>
    <button class="button" id="si" type="button" disabled>Si</button>
    <button class="button" id="no" type="button" disabled>No</button>
    <button class="button" id="ver" type="button" disabled>Ver Resultado</button>
  </div>
  <div id="resultado">
  </div>
</div>
```

Con esto espero poder aclarar un poco las dudas al respecto, y ejemplificar la forma en la que podemos usar tanto `setTimeout()` como `setInterval()`.

Comment: muchas gracias por la claridad y excelente explicación seguí tus recomendaciones y me funcionó